# Not able to create xml file on remote server using php

Tags: php, mysql, xml, dom

I am developing a php app where I need to fetch some data from MySQL database and create an xml file. I have succeeded in doing that in my local server(XAMPP on Windows) but, when I tried to load it from remote server(Linux) I am not getting any output.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 
$connection=mysql_connect ($host, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());} 
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
} 
$query = "SELECT * FROM tracker WHERE 1 LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {  
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} 

header("Content-type: text/xml"); 
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);  
} 
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

Output I got on local machine:
`

```
<markers>
<marker lat="17" lng="77"/>
</markers>
```

On remote server I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Have you checked your error_log file? It should indicate what the server error is.

Comment: Solved. I checked the error log and the problem was with the use of strtotime() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause can be many-fold - access rights, xml libraries you are missing, php version...

can you check the error_log file

**/var/log/httpd/error_log on RHEL**

or

**/var/log/apache2/error_log on DEB**

and paste the output from the error?